# How do i use ReorderableListView with a ListView.builder

Tags: flutter

i'm trying to make my list reorderable, i have followed some tutorials on using the ReorderableListView but it doesn't work for the type of list i'm using. What should i do?

Code before ReorderableListView

```
      body: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: db.toDoList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return toDoTile(
        taskName: db.toDoList[index][0],
        taskCompleted: db.toDoList[index][1],
        onChanged: (value) => checkBoxChanged(value, index),
        deleteFunction: (context) => deleteTask(index),
        editTask: (context) => editTask(index),
      );
```

When doing tutorials on ReorderableListView I end up with this:

```
body: ReorderableListView(
    children: [
      for (final tile in myTiles)
        ListTile(
          key: ValueKey(tile),
          title: Text(tile),
        )
    ],
    onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) => updatMyTiles(oldIndex, newIndex),
  ),
```

but the question is how do i implement the two together?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView/ReorderableListView.builder.html

Combined, it would then look something like this:

```
ReorderableListView.builder(
    itemCount: db.toDoList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return toDoTile(
        taskName: db.toDoList[index][0],
        taskCompleted: db.toDoList[index][1],
        onChanged: (value) => checkBoxChanged(value, index),
        deleteFunction: (context) => deleteTask(index),
        editTask: (context) => editTask(index),
      );
    },
    onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) => updatMyTiles(oldIndex, newIndex),
```

I personally have a property on my model that has its index, so I can save its state.

Comment: Hey I tried it but its saying onReorder isn't being used, do you know why that would be happening?

Comment: Missed a brace, check the answer again.